# view can't recognize gesture

Tags: ios, view, uigesturerecognizer, overlap

I got two views,view A and view B, which are on the same level, and they have overlap area.  View A has a tap gesture, but in the overlap area, view A would not recognize the gesture, it's fine out of the overlap area,what would I do to make view A recognize the gesture in the overlap area?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewA] in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Nope，I have to retain view B in front of self.view too

Comment: But you can't retain 2 views in front at the same time. When you should 'catch' gesture, put ViewA in front.

Comment: Can you add some code? I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Here is the thing, I want to clip photo in a rectangle, So I implement a custom view called view B which has a rectangle frame in the center of it,and I have a scroll view called view A that hold a image view, so view A and view B are both added to self.view, once I invoke [self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewA] ,view B would disappear, and that is not what I want.

Comment: ViewA is inside ViewB?

Comment: Sure, here is the code:self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];[self.view addSubView:self.scrollView];self.customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];[self.view addSubView:self.customView]; So self.scrollView is View A,and self.customView is View B

Comment: But here ViewB totally 'covered' VievA. So ViewA is like 'invisible'. How it can responce to your recogniser?

Comment: Just add recogniser to ViewB.

Comment: Solved, it's pretty easy, just set view B's userInteractionEnabled to NO, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Oleshko said, you can bring the `viewA` to front or you can just add `viewA` after `viewB` to the superview.